# getExpoPushTokenAsync not working on Standalone app

Tags: react-native, expo

```
  const token = await Notifications.getExpoPushTokenAsync()


   await axiosConfig.post("pushToken", { token });
```

this code works perfectly on (Production mode and Expo Client app) 
When i use expo build:android for APK. app crash when I call this function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try out:
For a ./google-services.json:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "…",
    "firebase_url": "…",
    "project_id": "…",
    "storage_bucket": "…"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "…",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "…"
        }
      },
      "api_key": [
        {
          "current_key": "KEY_KEY_KEY_KEY_KEY"
        }
      ]
    },
```

please make app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "…": "…",
    "android": {
      "package": "…",
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json",
      "config": {
        "googleSignIn": {
          "apiKey": "KEY_KEY_KEY_KEY_KEY"
        }
      }
```

https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/7727#issuecomment-611544439

Comment: Yeah! it's work. Btw Expo team should add this step to Docs!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I solved it by enabling my notification for Expo client on my device.